# DataGrid.ItemsSource.Refresh() not working

Tags: wpf, datagrid, refresh

I have a wpf form which contains a datagrid. I did put a button on my form to "Refresh" the datagrid. Steps I'm trying to get it to refresh:

1. I update the viewsource from my db:
   SupportCaseViewSource.Source = SupportCaseManager.GetAllSupportCases();
2. I refresh the datagrid items:
   SupportCaseDataGrid.Items.Refresh();

But nothing happens...no new data displayed!!

Has someone an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Beat

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually instructing your controls to refresh, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `PropertyChanged` with appropriate arguments. In your case this is probably

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Source"));
```

It'll be whatever is bound to the `SupportCaseDataGrid.ItemsSource`.